# Able to GET authenticate but not POST authenticate

Tags: web-services, authentication, rest, curl

I am trying to connect to a REST API, using C#.
I was able to successfully do some GET request but POST kept giving me 401 Authentication error.

I have gone ahead and downloaded fiddler and this is what my requests look like:

GET (Works)

Request Headers

```
GET https: //hello.myurl.com/api HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/xml
Authorization: Basic ***************************************************************************************************
Host: hello.myurl.com
```

-

POST (Doesn't work)

Request Headers

```
POST https: //hello.myurl.com/api HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/xml
Authorization: Basic ***************************************************************************************************
Host: hello.myurl.com
Content-Length: 12
```

Request Body

```
status=hello
```

(*** same in both using

```
String authinfo = "username:password";
Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authInfo));
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: did you write the webservice or is it someone elses? It looks from what you have said as if some of the methods have authentication on them

Comment: But I am sending the authentication details.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consult the API documentation for that particular URL. GET requests are simply requesting a readonly version of data, a POST request is implying that you are making a change to a certain URL, so it's possible that the API allows GET requests without authentication, but requires authentication on the POST request.

In your case I'd hazard a guess that your authentication is not correct, but it's just being ignored on the GET request as it doesnt need authentication.